# Should I make a local variable into a member variable for performance?

Tags: oop, scope, software-design

A local variable that is not a basic type requires instantiation each time the function is called.  In the simplest of cases, for performance reasons, these local variables can be changed to be member variables so that they are only ever created once.  However, is it worth the loss in maintainability?  Is there a rule for when it is good to move local variable to member variables?

Comment: please specify language because it really matters

Comment: Local variables don't take any time to instantiate. Calling a function has to create a stack frame, adding another local variable simply increases the size of the frame.

Comment: I should clarify that -- it only applies if the object has no constructor.

Comment: I'm interested in C++ and Java.  Though, please explain why the language matters (much).

Comment: Many languages initialize base objects to a default value, even if their is no constructor (which is an operation).  But you are correct in that memory does not need to be allocated for local variables, which is useful to take into account for this discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules I follow are the other way around, and they both suggest that you shouldn't change a variable which is naturally a local variable into a member variable for performance unless you really, really need to:

- **First make your program correct, then make it clear, then make it fast.** The optimization you're suggesting will make your program less clear, because your readers' default expectation is that member variables say something about the object instance, rather than just being a slot for some incidental calculation. I would only make it if I'd already determined that the method with the local was performance-critical, and if making the change would significantly improve performance.
- **Give every variable the minimum scope and lifetime that it can have while still doing its job.** That reduces bugs due to mistaken reuse of old values and makes your program easier to read (because there is less state to think about for any given line). Members are better in this respect than globals; locals are better than members. So if a variable can be a local, it should be.

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself

Comment: Nevermind.. I misread it.  Your answer is confusing "don't make a local a member" reads like "don't make a local".  I would reword it to be clearer.  I would say "Don't use a member when a local is appropriate, or something like that.